# Windows Certificate Store, get last access date for a certificate or set up access logging for it.

Tags: windows-server-2008, certificate

On Windows Server 2008 I have a certificate in Local Computer store. The certificate is about to expire, but i'm not sure if anything actually uses it. Is there a way that I can get something like a last usage date for it? Maybe I can set up some watch to monitor its usage (i still have about a month before it expires)?

Comment: You can't really know that if you don't know it already. I would go in this direction: carefully analyze take a list of installed roles/applications and then check each role/application if there are visible bindings with this certificates. If no results, then I would delete the cert and see what fails. You have to pay for a lack of internal documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type from the certificate. So if that's a webserver certificate for example you scan the server and all ports to check if it comes up there.

By the way i would never delete the certificate. Try to export that at first so you can restore it if needed.